# Coldfusion cfdocument pagebreak issue

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

```
<cfif currentrow mod #Arguments.numbersDown# is 0>
 <cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak"/>
</cfif>
```

I am planning on using a page break after the record number reaches the specified number (numbersDown). However the above code will print several pages then print the records on the last page.
Is there anyway to solve this problem or another way to force a page break?

Note: The above code is within a table.

Comment: Please [update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32971868/edit) with a *small*, self-contained example that demonstrates the issue you described.

Comment: With little so ever information:

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.  did not work for me too. however similar could be achieved with 'header':

```
 <cfdocument format="PDF" filename="#local.sTargetPDFName#" overwrite="yes" orientation="portrait"  marginright=".2" marginleft=".2" marginbottom=".2" margintop=".2" localURL='Yes'>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <cfset   dPerPage=local.qPHForm10A.recordCount/2 />
            <cfset sRow=1 />    
            <cfloop index="local.nowIndx" from="1" to="#dPerPage#">
                <cfset eRow=sRow +2 />
                   <tr>
                     <th align="center" bgcolor="##efefef" class="noBorder">Account</th>
                     <th align="center" bgcolor="##efefef" class="noBorder">Funds</th>
                     <th align="center" bgcolor="##efefef" class="noBorder">Balance</th>
                   </tr>
                   <cfloop query="local.qPHForm10A" startrow="#sRow#" endrow="#eRow#">

                   <tr>
                     <td class="noBorder noPadding">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="borderList" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="noleftBorder">#DateFormat(rc.qPayementHistoryForm10A.PAYMENT_DATE,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
                            <td>#local.qPHForm10A.VAL1#</td>
                            <td>#local.qPHForm10A.VAL2#</td>
                            <td>#local.qPHForm10A.VAL3#</td>
                          </tr>
                       </table>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                 </cfloop>
                 <cfset sRow=sRow+2 />
                 <cfdocumentitem type="header"></cfdocumentitem>
                </cfloop>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</cfdocument>
```